# whether other iOS except iOS 5 will support this framework or not?

Tags: iphone, xcode, twitter, ios4, ios5

I am not getting any good code for integrating text with image upload on twitter using iphone sdk. I found that with release of iOS 5 a framework named Twitter.Framework is also released. Will this framework be supported on older iOS?

Answer (score 1):

No, Twitter integration got introduced in iOS 5. You'll need to find a third party library for older versions of iOS.